# Android string variable always final in R.java

Tags: java, android, variables, r.java-file

I am building a simple java/android application, and am trying to change the value of a string (which is used as the text of a button) stored in the resources file.

Whenever I try to change the the value (using R.string.), I get an error. This is because in this file (the R.string one), the variable is "final". Whenever I try to edit the file, it reverts it to the original version.

If there a way to stop this string being final, or is there another way to pass values for the text property of something like this?

Comment: Don't change the value of the string, change the button's text value. `R` is auto-generated, don't edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not able to modify the R file directly (it is auto-generated as part of the build process).

If you want to change the label of a button, you could set it in the code like this:

myButton.setText(R.string.myString)

if you would like to change it to a different string, you could always just set it to another predefined String like this:

myButton.setText(R.string.myOtherString)

The R class will automatically make references to Strings from your strings.xml file (which should be in the res\values folder)

Comment: Thanks for that. I now have `R.id.textView1.setText("4");`, but I get this error: "Cannot invoke setText(int) on the primitive type int. Thanks

Comment: You need to resolve your button first:

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);

tv.setText("4");

You need to do it in 2 steps.

Answer (score 5):

Don't change the value of the string, change the button's text value.

`R` is auto-generated, don't edit it.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I change the button's text value? I'm a bit of a n00b here.

Comment: @ACarter pass a different string to `setText()`.

Comment: @ACarter What Matt said; see the [setText() docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Resources are static. Period. And R/Class is generated from your xml resource declarations.  If you like to store editable values use preferences.